# Use iframes within Ruby Shoes?

Tags: ruby, shoes

Is it possible use an iframe within ruby shoes? I want to try displaying a PDF within the app....

I have not tried anything yet because I am not sure what works.

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can try for creating pdfs 
`gem 'wicked_pdf'`